# Find a regular expression in between two characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a txt file which contains the following line.

```
<KEY key="Spread" keyvalue="FILENAME">
```

How can I extract FILENAME from the above using regular expressions
So far I have tried (in my python script):

```
if '"Spread" keyvalue' in line:
    n = re.search(r'\keyvalue="(.*)', line)
    name = n.group()
    print name
```

This gives an output of:

```
keyvalue="FILENAME">
```

but I only want to output:

```
FILENAME
```

What is the regular expression I need?

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex to,

```
n = re.search(r'\bkeyvalue="(.*?)"', line)
name = n.group(1)
```

*Example:*

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''<KEY key="Spread" keyvalue="FILENAME">'''
>>> n = re.search(r'\bkeyvalue="(.*?)"', s)
>>> n.group(1)
'FILENAME'
>>>
```

*OR*

Use BeautifulSoup.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> xml = '''<KEY key="Spread" keyvalue="FILENAME">'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'lxml')
>>> s = soup.find('key', attrs={'key':'Spread'})
>>> s.get('keyvalue', None)
'FILENAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another pattern to try:

```
>>> line = '<KEY key="Spread" keyvalue="FILENAME">'
>>> re.findall('\s+keyvalue=\"([^"]+)\"', line)
['FILENAME']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex. I'm using lookbehind feature.:

```
(?<=keyvalue=\").*?(?=\")
```

Your code should look like:

```
line = '<KEY key="Spread" keyvalue="FILENAME">'

match = re.search(r"(?<=keyvalue=\").*?(?=\")", line, re.MULTILINE)
if match:
    result = match.group()
    print(result)
```

If match is successful, it should print `FILENAME`.